# How to find which treatment is most effective in gene data given one standard method and 3 variations

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Sorry I am a biologist and it appears am not quite confident enough for statistical analysis. I have datasets that represent different treatments on a biological system. It records how many genes have increased expression.
my results are

40/409 genes,

30/412 genes,

15/407 genes,

24/430 genes

How would I go about finding if there is a statistical difference between the tests? If I wanted to know which has the lowest, or highest affect how would I go about it?

Comment: [These guys](http://stats.stackexchange.com) should know better. Personally I don't understand what you are asking, maybe you need to develop a bit more on what your numbers represent, if this is all the data you have and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @gsmafra Thank you, I didn't know where to put this.

Comment: @stevensown: if you have the sample errors, you can use ANOVA , e.g.http://brownmath.com/stat/anova1.htm , but I am not sure how to work with the proportions alone, without the SEs.:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned with whether the chance of increased expression differs at all between the four treatment groups, you might start off with a likelihood ratio test for checking whether $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = p_4$, where $p_i$ is the probability of increased expression within treatment group $i$.

The likelihood ratio will compare the maximum likelihood of the data when all probabilities are constrained to be equal (the null hypothesis) to the maximum likelihood when all four are allowed to vary (the alternative).  Notice that within group $i$ the number with increased expression can be assumed binomially distributed with parameters $n_i$ and $p_i$, and so our likelihood function will be a *product* of binomial probabilities.  Specifically, if $x_i$ is the number with increased expression within group $i$, $\hat{p}_i \equiv x_i / n_i$, and $\hat{p} \equiv (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4) / (n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4)$ (these are the estimates which maximize the likelihood under the two hypotheses) the likelihood ratio becomes,

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda(x) = \frac{\hat{p}^{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} (1 - \hat{p})^{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3 - x_4}}{\hat{p}_1^{x_1} (1 - \hat{p}_1)^{n_1 - x_1} \hat{p}_2^{x_2} (1 - \hat{p}_2)^{n_2 - x_2} \hat{p}_3^{x_3} (1 - \hat{p}_3)^{n_3 - x_3} \hat{p}_4^{x_4} (1 - \hat{p}_4)^{n_4 - x_4}} .
\end{align}
$$

Once you've computed this value, there's theory that says $- 2 \log [\Lambda(x)] \sim \chi^2_3$ under the null hypothesis, where $\chi^2_3$ refers to a chi-squared distribution with three degrees of freedom.  This will allow you to compute an approximate $p$-value and determine if there's evidence that the probabilities differ.

For trying to determine pairwise differences, you could probably just use standard $z$ tests where your test statistic will take the form,

$$
z = \frac{\hat{p}_i - \hat{p}_j}{\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}_i(1 - \hat{p}_i)}{n_i} + \frac{\hat{p}_j(1 - \hat{p}_j)}{n_j}}} ,
$$

which approximately follows a standard normal distribution when $p_i = p_j$.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you @dsaxton, I think I figured out what your answer means. I looked up your first part and is there a difference between this and the contingency chi squared test?

Comment: Pearson's $\chi^2$ test is very similar to the likelihood ratio test and numerically the results are generally close.  Pearson's test would be checking for independence between the treatments and expression levels, which actually turns out to be the same as saying $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = p_4$.  When testing the pairwise differences, some would complain if you don't "adjust for multiple testing" (the chance that at least one of your conclusions is wrong increases as you do more tests) but I personally think multiple testing concerns are overblown and wouldn't worry about that here.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake in my original post and had the numerator and denominator reversed (it doesn't really matter until you want to say $- 2 \log[\Lambda(x)] \sim \chi^2$), but it should be correct now.  In any case, it may be easier to simply run Pearson's test since most software packages will have automatic procedures for doing this.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation! Looking at the wikipedia page just now, I don't think I could have really figured that out.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.